# two multiple selector in a single data table primefaces

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I want two multiple selectors in a single data table. Is that possible or not ?
or how i can obtain that...
[image: here two tables with two selectors....]

i want a single table and two selectors need to point different values.
please share your ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i actually done that using simple css and jsf UI repeat tag.........